# IF function use within SQL help needed (New to SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, dateadd, getdate

Apologies if my question is not clear, I am new to this!

I've got data going back 3 years and I want the **364DaysFlag** column to return 1 if the date within the InsertDateTime column (which consists of both the date and time) is within the last 364 days and to return 0 if the InsertDateTime is older than 364 days.

Just to make it clear, the Transaction.tbl.Flag table is dynamic/live so everyday the most recent day is added and this is where I come unstuck in order to get it to work!

Below is the incorrect code (which runs but does not do what I want) that I've used and where I made it bold is where it needs updating.

```
SELECT TransactionDate, TotalCustomers, [1 as 364DaysFlag], InsertDateTime
INTO Transaction.tbl.Flag
FROM Performance.Sales.Total
```

Please could someone advise on how I can get this to work? Do I need to use an IF function or something else? DO I need a DATEADD and/or GETDATE function? I am fairly new to SQL and still learning! :)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your sample code makes no sense.  There is no `INTO` statement in MySQL (there is an `INTO` clause, but that is not how a query begins).

Comment: ```SELECT TransactionDate, TotalCustomers, InsertDateTime > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 364 DAY AS 364DaysFlag, InsertDateTime ...```. Of course, not SELECT INTO - retrieve `364DaysFlag` column value by the common way.

Comment: @Akina how do I get it so the L364D column returns 1 if date is within 364 days and 0 if older than 364 days?

Comment: Use my SQL text fragment as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TransactionDate
    , TotalCustomers
    , CASE WHEN /*DateColumn*/ > (GETDATE()-365) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS /*ColumnAlias*/
    , InsertDateTime
INTO database.schema.table
FROM Performance.Sales.Total
```

FYI, try to not start a column with a number. Also since it's a flag, try to convert it into a couple of word question like 'RecentSale' or something similar to that to where 1 = yes being a recent sale and 0 being not recent.